How to get the value of visual-mode wordcount() in lua script
Objective
I am working on writing a keymap through lua script in Neovim:

First, selecting some words in visual mode and, in the corresponding lua script, trying to get the value of vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words which I expect it return the word count in my selected region for later usage.
Then, (keep the selected text in visual mode from the previous step,) use the keymap to do something.

I've found some information as follows

https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#wordcount()
https://neovim.io/doc/user/editing.html#v_g_CTRL-G


What I tried
For trial, for instance, in a file containing the text
,,,, ,,, ,,,,, ,,  ,,,

:lua print(vim.fn.wordcount().words) gives 5 in status massage (v:statusmsg).
However, when I tried to get vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words after selecting some text (shown by being surrounded by a pair of |) as follows
,,,, ,,, |,,,,, ,,  ,,,|

both of :'< '> lua print(vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words) or :lua print(vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words) (manually delete '< '>) give nil.
For the same selected text (in visual mode), the keystroke g<C-g> and then :echo v:statusmsg gives the result Selected 1 of 1 Lines; 3 of Words; 13 of 25 Bytes.

It seems that I use vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words in the wrong way but the manual https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#wordcount() doesn't explicitly guide us the correct way to use.
How can I use the information from vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words in lua? Could someone help? Thanks.

help topic for wordcount is a direct replica of what vim has and in vim it might be called using <cmd>, e.g. xnoremap <c-l> <cmd>echow wordcount()<CR>.

Thanks! It helps!

As Maxim Kim commented, using : exits visual mode, and wordcount() will not have the key .visual_words (since that is only available in visual mode). The workaround is to use <cmd> in the mapping, such as
xnoremap <C-l> <cmd>echo wordcount().visual_words)<CR>

In lua, this would be
vim.keymap.set('x', '<C-l>', "<cmd>lua print(vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words)<CR>")


Thanks for replying; it really helps!
